# Does `std::any_cast<T>` require `T` to be constructible even when asked for a pointer?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I want to `std::any` to contain `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;
  Foo(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo(Foo&&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};

void f() {
  using std::any;
  using std::any_cast;
  using std::unique_ptr;
  using std::vector;
  using V = vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>;

  any a(V());
  V* v = any_cast<V>(&a);
}
```

According to [the document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast), `std::any_cast<T>(&a)` seems to return `V*`. I think this doesn't copy the contained object.
But when I tried to compile the above code, I got the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Foo; _Dp = std::default_delete<Foo>]’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does it means that `std::any_cast<V>(&a)` requires `V` to be constructible? Does `std::any_cast` copy the contained object even when it is simply asked for a pointer? If so, why does it need to copy the content?

Comment: `a` is function that takes a `V` and returns an `any`.

Comment: If you fix the declaration of `a` - `any a(V{})` - you will notice that you get an error without `any_cast`. This is because anything you put in an `any` must be copy-constructible.

Comment: Relevant: [std::any for objects that can't be copy constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46852168/580083)

Comment: @molbdnilo  I misunderstood the problem. I fixed the declaration and removed the line in which `any_cast` is called, then I recompiled the code but still got the same error. So I see `any_cast` is not an issue.

Comment: @snbn That was exactly what molbdnilo pointed out. The problem is not with `any_cast`. The problem is that you can't put into `std::any` an object of a non-copyable type (such as `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<whatever>>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::any` uses type-erasure techniques. And that means that whatever requirements are imposed on the erased type must be detected at the time when you erase the type. This is different from a template type, where it can assess the requirements when you invoke a function that actually uses those requirements.

So even if you don't do the thing that actually needs it, `any` still imposes those requirements.

That having been said, in this case you *are* doing the thing that actually needs it. Namely, `any a(V());`. It will copy the object into the internal storage of `a`. Remember: you can't do copy elision through a function parameter.

Comment: When compiling, it is not determined whether the content of `std::any` will copyable or not, therefore `std::any` always requires its content to be copyable. Is it right?